# Excel date data prepare

Tags: formula, excel

I have a date field value in an excel column as 9/2/2016.

I need to use text formula to put the value like this 09-02-2016. I know if I manually enter such a value it will automatically take it as 9/2/2016. I need to put '09-02-2016 to get my desired output. Now the problem is I need to build this thing using FORMULA TEXT and concatenation in a column beside where the data rests.

Can someone let me know how to achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi. You need a text formula field returning your date field but with this format: 'dd-MM-yyyy'?

Comment: How to get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the formula:

```
IF(DAY( YourDate) < 10, '0' & TEXT(DAY( YourDate)), TEXT(DAY( YourDate))) & '-' & IF(MONTH( YourDate) < 10, '0' & TEXT(MONTH( YourDate)), TEXT(MONTH( YourDate))) & '-' & TEXT(YEAR( YourDate))
```

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help.